# How to construct geographies from WKTs

Tags: sql-server, spatial-database, well-known-text

I am using a SQL Server 2012 database. I have noticed that geometries and geographies interpret WKTs differently. For instance, if I construct a *square* polygon, clockwise:

```
DECLARE @geom Geometry=geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-30 -45, -30 45, 30 45, 30 -45, -30 -45))', 4326)
DECLARE @geog Geography=geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-30 -45, -30 45, 30 45, 30 -45, -30 -45))', 4326)
```

The geometry will be interpreted (as intended) as the original square (*inwards*):
[image: geometry]

But the geography will be interpreted as the complement of the square (*outwards*):
[image]

Is this standard (and can you find a reference to why this is so)? And if so, how is it possible to construct a geography from a WKT?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "complement of the square", just a great circle route.  It's a 
feature of the GEOGRAPHY type to compute great circle routes on the spheroid.
You can read more about it [here](http://uxblog.idvsolutions.com/2010/03/geometry-and-geography-in-sql-server.html). The only way to follow a parallel would
be to use an insane number of vertices between the meridians.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me: I am not annoyed at the shape of it. The problem is that in one case (geometry) the polygon defines the area inside the square, whereas in the other case (geography) the polygon defines the area outside the square...

Comment: Ahh.  The change in colors threw me off.  The orientation of your ring is correct (left hand rule), but SQL-Server is misinterpreting it.  Try flipping the rotation of your ring to be right-hand rule.  Alternatively, try casting from a Geometry type.